# IONIC Framework - template getting reloaded multiple times

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

(Demo of issue added at CodePen, url given below)
In app.js I have my routings defined as..

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login1',
          templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
          controller: 'AuthSignUpCtrl'
    });
```

and in login.html just to test I have called a method

```
{{test()}}
```

and in controller I have just created a test fn which just consoles & it gets called for 9-10 times

Note: I have verified, controller is getting loaded only once not multiple times. Also, If I add more routes in app.js the number of print keeps increasing as well.

Hope someone can help.

EDIT: controller fn

```
.controller('AuthSignUpCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.test = function() {
    console.log(44)
  };
});
```

Result:

```
controllers.js:72 44
controllers.js:72 44
2controllers.js:72 44
5controllers.js:72 44
controllers.js:72 44
controllers.js:72 44
4controllers.js:72 44
controllers.js:72 44
controllers.js:72 44
```

Issue demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXxxpM

Comment: Can you provide your controller function where you put consoles.

Comment: Added the controller code alongwith the question

Comment: where is you Controller mapped with app? it should `app.controller`

Comment: Yes it is like that only, its working because they are mapped otherwise it won't be connected & working.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle/plunker which shows your issue? :)

Comment: actually issue is with IONIC,so cant do a proper setup for that app.

Comment: Check if you remove ioinc  routing is it working as per expected?

Comment: Code added at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXxxpM

Answer (score 0):

Angular bindings will keep updating until it gets a `stabilized value`. Since your function is not returning anything and only doing a console, therefore it is being called multiple times. Try to return some string after console and it will not be called multiple times.